# How to proxy httpd call using netcat (nc)

Tags: apache, proxy, httpd.conf, netcat

I have a proxy pass which redirects all BE service calls to the API-Gateway. For debugging one particular scenario, I want to proxy all urls with base path `/abc` to a netcat proxy which would dumplt the complete request on console.

ATM I am using following proxy pass:

```
ProxyPass /abc/ http://localhost:8089/apigateway/api/
```

Whereas I am listening on port `8089` as follow:

```
nc -p 8089 localhost 8080
```

But the `nc` connection is closing up within few seconds after i run the above mentioned command. Any idea what am I do wrong?

When I curl the url `http://localhost/abc/messaage`, I see 503 as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:
    sudo nc -l localhost 8089 < abc.txt | tee -a in | nc localhost 8080 | tee -a out.html > def.txt

Listening on port 8089 (httpd forwards everything on 8089). `nc` then forwards the request to port 8080 (actual apigateway). In the middle it dumps the request and response in different files.